# Extend Codeigniter Exceptions class to add a custom method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I created a new method to handle with 401 apache error.

My core class extends CI core class but when I call the method name I receive this message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `show_401()` in
>   `G:\Path\application\controllers\loader.php` on line 29

```php
class MI_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * 401 Unauthorized
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string  the page
     * @param   bool    log error yes/no
     * @return  string
     */
    function show_401($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        $heading = "401 Unauthorized";
        $message = "Unauthorized.";

        // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
        if ($log_error)
        {
            log_message('error', '401 Unauthorized --> '.$page);
        }

        echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_401', 401);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try with `public function show_401(` ?

Comment: Yep! And that don't work too. Core are autoloaded by CodeIgniter right? Or I need to load core, like I load a lib?

Comment: @user3108967 Post the `controllers/loader.php` (Controller) file as well.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami Just calling show_401();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have extended the Exceptions core class right.

*Just make sure that you've set the `subclass_prefix` config as follows:*

```php
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MI_';
```

However it seems you have used the `show_401()` function directly within your Controller.

The point is that you **can't** access the class methods as a function in **global scope**.
 In other words, you **have to** create an **instance** of the class to access the `show_401()` method.

### But how does `show_404()` built-in function work?

That's because CodeIgniter has created **[a Common function](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Common.php#L328-L333)** for that method which helps the users to use the [`Exception::show_404()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Exceptions.php#L104-L117) method in global scope.

**system/core/Common.php**

```php
function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
    $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
    $_error->show_404($page, $log_error);
    exit;
}
```

The function uses another common function named `load_class()` to get the instance of the Exceptions core class ([returning by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)) in order to access the `show_404()` method.

> Common functions as the same as helper functions, but [they're loaded
>   at very beginning of the application](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L51).

### Getting `show_401()` function to work

In order to use this function in global scope, you could create a helper function to create an instance of the class, and access you're custom method.

There's no *Exceptions* built-in helper file in CodeIgniter. Thus, you could create `exceptions_helper.php` file inside `application/helpers/` folder to add your helper function:

**application/helpers/exceptions_helper.php**

```php
if ( ! function_exists('show_401'))
{
    function show_401($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
        $_error->show_401($page, $log_error);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Finally, load the helper file within your Controller:

```php
$this->load->helper('exceptions');

// Then use the function
show_401();
```

You could also load the helper file automatically (if it's necessary to be loaded always) by adding the helper name into the `autoload.php` config file:

```php
$autoload['helper'] = array('exceptions'/*, 'language', 'form'*/);
```

Comment: Could I extend the Common core?

Comment: @user3108967 `Common.php` core file is not a *Class* and it's not possible to extend that because it is loaded at the beginning of the application. The best approach is using a custom helper file as I suggested :)