# Custom view in show_404() not working

Tags: codeigniter, exception, error-handling, routes, http-status-code-404

I have tried both 404_override and MY_Exceptions for showing custom error view. Can somebody please help me with it?

Here is the 404_override code

Routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error/index';
```

Error.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Error extends CI_Controller {

    public $user_id ='';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('login.php');
        $user_Details = $this->login_library->get_user_details();
        $this->user_id = $user_Details['user_id'];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
         $this->output->set_status_header('404');  
        $this->load->view('view_header',$this->user_id); 
        $this->load->view('view_404');
        $this->load->view('view_footer',$this->user_id);     
    }



}
```

Here is the My_Exceptions code

```
<?php  if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{

    function MY_Exceptions(){
        parent::CI_Exceptions();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function show_404($page=''){ 
        echo $heading = "404 Page Not Found";
        echo $message = "The ppage you requested was not found.";
        $this->config =& get_config();
        $baseUrl = $this->config['base_url'];
        header("location: ".$baseUrl.'error.html');
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure about what you're trying to achieve, however this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735851/extend-codeigniter-exceptions-class-to-add-a-custom-method/21739026#21739026

Comment: I thought that was quite explanatory. It's a simple question. Is it any way to do it with $route['404_override']?

Comment: If you want to use a custom 404 error page, you don't have to extend the `CI_Exception` core class, your `Error` controller seems fine to me. Echo out the `$this->user_id` in `index()` method to make sure it works.

Comment: It's not working. I tried both the things i.e. routes.php and my_exceptions but my bad. I don't know where the hell am I doing mistake. I should try a new CI project and 404_override to check if it's my other project things doing it or is it a CI bug.

Comment: It's not working in my version but It's working in the new version. Thanks. Help appreciated.

I have also tried show_404() wherever I want to call that error function but it's not working. Help appreciated.

Comment: You can see both the version. 404_override custom view is showing me the page that I want - http://s11.postimg.org/a9oozn3o3/Screen_Shot_2014_03_21_at_1_01_54_AM.png

where as when I call show_404, it shows me page not found i.e. error_404() method from errors folder - http://s27.postimg.org/5ga9d5v1f/Screen_Shot_2014_03_21_at_1_01_44_AM.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter 2.1 issue with show\_404() and 404\_override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422033/codeigniter-2-1-issue-with-show-404-and-404-override)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the solution from this link - [CodeIgniter 2.1 issue with show_404() and 404_override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422033/codeigniter-2-1-issue-with-show-404-and-404-override).

```
<?php
// application/core/MY_Exceptions.php
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function show_404()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->view('my_notfound_view');
        echo $CI->output->get_output();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for all the help. Appreciated :)

Comment: It doesn't. It overrides it for custom behavior, this is comonly done.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show custom 404 template

You need to change $route['404_override'] = 'welcome/page_not_found'; in config/routes.php file.

and write the action in controller

```
public function page_not_found(){
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Page Not Found!';
    $this->load->view('layouts/page_not_found.php', $this->data);
}
```

Important:Your page_not_found action should be in your default controller
(You can set default controller from config/routes.php, $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';)

Answer (score 0):

Try to changing the config.php to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

it work ?.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and tried extending the Exceptions class, but codegniter wasn't supporting extending the Exceptions class

This is what worked for me, in order to override the show_404() method

create a helper method

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_show_404'))
{
    /**
    * Method Name custom_show_404
    *
    */
    function custom_show_404()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->view("not_found_page");

        //log message
        log_message('error','PAGE NOT FOUND ETC...');
    }
}
```

after that find and replace all `show_404()` method calls with `custom_show_404()` in the application/controllers folder

Note: don't forget to load the helper file that contains your new method

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late to answer this question, but maybe that will help anyone else looking for a solution to this problem.

I tried the [answer](http://#22567953) proposed by [Chopra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214867/chopra) but it's not working, because the `show_404` signature must be same as the one it overrides.

I have replaced the core class `CI_Exceptions` with that new one.

```
<?php
// application/core/MY_Exception.php
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    /**
     * Show a custom 404 error
     */
    public function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $data['title'] = '404 Page Not Found!';
        $output = '';
        $output .= $CI->load->view('templates/header', $data, true);
        $output .= $CI->load->view('error_404', '', true);
        $output .= $CI->load->view('templates/footer', $data, true);
        set_status_header(404);
        echo $output;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the core file of CodeIgniter to use custom 404 pages through show_404() function. Just go to \system\core\Common.php and replace show_404() function with following code:

```
function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
     $ci = get_instance();
     $ci->output->set_status_header(404);
     $ci->load->view('404');
     echo $ci->output->get_output();
     exit(4);
}
```

> Note: Please replace **Your_custom_404_page** text with your custom
>   404 page.

It's working properly on my own Codeigniter Application. I hope it will work properly